# In the .bmp file structure on windows, why is "biSizeImage" not equal to "width * height * (biBitCount / 8)"?

Tags: file-format, bmp

I wrote a program to read the .bmp file. Here is the information of this the .bmp file:

[image: running result]

here is another test image：

[image: another test]

I found the "biSizeImage" not equal to "width * height * (biBitCount / 8)", why does that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each scanline is padded to a multiple of 4 bytes.

In your image, the width is 1190 pixels, each taking 24 bits / 8 bits/byte = 3 bytes. This needs 1190 pixels/scanline * 3 bytes/pixel = 3570 bytes/scanline. This value is rounded up to 3572 bytes per scanline, making it a multiple of 4 bytes. You then have 3572 bytes / scanline * 685 scanlines = 2446820 bytes for the image.

Comment: Blast! Connections problems prevented me from seeing the other answer posted as I was writing mine.

Comment: Thank you too : ), could you help me to figure the reason of second picture out? I running another test and get a strange result (the second picture in the program content) : the width is multiple of 4 already, but the biSIzeImage is not equal to the calculate result 400 * 649 * 3 = 778800.

Comment: I'm not certain about the second image you added. There may be additional padding around the image, which is perhaps included in the count, if present. You might also want to look at the alignment of the base address of the image data. I'd be curious to know if the base address is not a multiple of 4 for that one image.

Comment: Thank you! it's could be the reason of this offset. I tried to print the address of image data in memory after read the bmp file. the address is multiple of 4. Is it possible that this deviation occurs in the hard disk?

Comment: I mean the file offset of the image data. Sorry, I should have been more clear with my language. My best guess right now is there is extra padding in the file around the image data. In particular, it would be peculiar to pad the scanlines to 4 bytes if the start of the data was not 4 byte aligned. Mind you, I doubt this would show up as the start offset being misaligned. It might simply be different from other image files due to a difference in padding before the start address. I wouldn't think such padding would be included in the count though. Might just be an incorrect header field.

Comment: Ah, I tried to read 778802 byte from this file and get them success, No Segment fault. Than I drop the last two byte of the image data off, modify the header information, write them to a new file, it's still able to display properly. It seems the extra padding is at the last two byte of image data. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

According to the BMP specification, each row is padded up to a multiple of 4 bytes.

In your case a row is 1190 pixels at 3 bytes per pixel. The raw size is 3570 bytes per row, so it gets rounded up to 3572 which is a multiple of 4.

From there, you can see that 3572 bytes per row × 685 rows = 2 446 820 bytes, exactly as needed.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I running another test and get a strange result (the second picture) : the width is multiple of 4 already, but the biSIzeImage is not equal to the calculate result 400 * 649 * 3 = 778800.

Comment: Yeah, the second one is strange. I don't have an answer for that.